# Form scrolling to last row instead of next

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

I have a table (1000 rows) and I am using a form to insert the data. When I open the form for the first time and enter in a record it works, the record gets inserted in the first row. Then when I press the "New" button when I enter the next record instead of it being inserted in the next row it gets inserted in the last row (1000th row) of the table.

I have no idea why. I thought the form would always enter in the next available row. PS I am not sure if this is important but I do have functions I use in some columns e.g. `=IF(I2="b", SUM(B2:F2),"")`

Can anyone explain why this is happening please and how to ensure the "next" record goes into the "next" row?

Comment: Hard to help explain whats going on or help you come up with an alternative without any code or example of what your code does.

Comment: Code? I just have a table in excel,initialized the form from excel to enter in records and when I click the new button in the form it creates a record for the last row instead of the next available.

Comment: By form, do you mean the generic Data Entry form in Excel?  Is column I part of your table?

Comment: yes the generic form and yes all columns are part of the form

Comment: It is something to do with the fact it is in a table. When I just have a plain excel sheet, the new record works perfectly, but in a table the new button puts the record in the last place.

Answer (score 0):

Try using <kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of "New".

It seems likely that you have already identified your problem - ie that the formula has already been automatically copied down in your table, hence the records (even if formula only) already exist - so the next new one is 1000.

Until `I2` is populated (and perhaps not even then) the formula returns a blank, so will not be evident - but is lurking for when required!

Comment: Thanks for the response, but unfortunatly 'enter' does not not work either.